# what is the correct way "brought" or "brang"?

Tags: grammar

My son uses the word *brang* all the time and my wife saying that it is ok.
I was taught that the proper past of "bring" is brought.

Who is right here?

Comment: Actually, you're more likely to hear *brung* than *brang* ... but you're right about *brought* being preferred or "proper" in English.

Answer (score 4):

*Brang* is a common (in the US, at least), but marked, past tense of *bring*. It is associated with less educated speakers in disadvantaged social groups. It is very uncommon among educated or high-social-standing speakers.

Comment: I have never ever heard "brang". I have heard "brung" occasionally. I suspect that "brang" must be peculiar to some American dialects.

Comment: @ColinFine, I would only know it from American usage, but I'm not the only one who's heard it: http://grammarist.com/usage/brung-brang/

Comment: @ColinFine: there's analogical basis for "brang", just as there is for "brung", so I wouldn't be surprised if both have a wide geographical distribution. There are a fair number of strong verbs that standardly have i/a/u like "ring, rang, rung", "sing, sang, sung", "spring, sprang, sprung" and while i/u (e.g. "sting, stung, stung") seems more common than i/a and is a common simplification for i/a/u, there are some verbs that seem to show a tendency to simplification to i/a like drink, drank, drunk/drank (possibly because speakers are trying to avoid confusion with the adjective/noun "drunk")

Comment: I would never, ever use "brang" in writing, but I do use it in speech (PacNW AmE)  Another fine article about the history and usage of bring/brang/brung in the US: http://www.nytimes.com/1996/11/17/magazine/bridge-to-past-tense.html

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=CeCuAVgRGCsC&pg=PA59&dq=%22brang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvgpDYgevWAhWLPCYKHXy6AeoQ6AEIfzAR#v=onepage&q=%22brang%22&f=false as an example of the register.

Answer (score 1):

While there are present/imperfect/perfect participle constructions like sing/sang/sung and ring/rang/rung, bring/brang/brung is *not* one of them.

From the Germanic origins of English we can see that for those verbs like *sing* the participles of sing/sang/sung correlate with the German singen/sang/gesungen, and that *bring* correlates with the German verb *bringen* - the English participles bring/brought/brought correlate with the German bringen/brachte/gebracht.

So no, *brang* is not correct (nor is *brung*). As noted it is a usage more common among less educated speakers.